# TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined react strapi in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, strapi

I'm using strapi with react. I'm fetching a JSON object (home). If I do `console.log(home)` I get:

```
{
  "id": 6,
  "created_at": "2020-06-21T07:07:36.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-06-21T07:18:40.000Z",
  "HomeTextTop": "Home text here.",
  "HomeTitle": "Home title here",
  "Hero": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "facade_pastel_summer_123664_800x600",
    "alternativeText": "",
    "caption": "",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600,
    "url": "http://someurlhere.com"
   }
}
```

If I `console.log(home.Hero)` I get the appropriate:

```
{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "facade_pastel_summer_123664_800x600",
   "alternativeText": "",
   "caption": "",
   "width": 800,
   "height": 600,
   "url": "http://someurlhere.com"
  }
```

However, if I drill down and try and get just the URL `console.log(home.Hero.url)` I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined react strapi in JSON object
```

What am I missing here?

The 'action' fetching code is:

```
export const fetchHome = () => {     
     return dispatch => {         
     dispatch(fetchHomeBegin())         
     return fetch(`${strapiUrl}/home`, {             
     method: 'get',             
     mode: 'cors',             
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }         
})             
.then(res => res.json())             
.then(json => {                 
console.log(json)                 
dispatch(fetchHomeSuccess(json))                 
})             
.catch(error => dispatch(fetchHomeFail(error)))     
}}
```

And `JSON.stringify(home.Hero)` gives the same result in string form

Comment: Do any other properties on `Hero` give you anything? May you also share your fetching code?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nothing from the Hero object gets returned, or I should say, is accessible

Comment: @evolutionxbox redux/actions/reducers:
```export const fetchHome = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchHomeBegin())
        return fetch(`${strapiUrl}/home`, {
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json)
                dispatch(fetchHomeSuccess(json))
                return json
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(fetchHomeFail(error)))
    }
}```

Comment: Sometimes logging can be inaccurate. May you try logging the hero object using JSON.stringify?

Comment: please may you remove the code comment and add it to the question?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Is the issue in strapi? Do I have to tell the model to return ALL attributes? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Andreas It is an object, and yes I understand the difference. Again, do you have anything that can help me solve this? I'm knew to strapi, do you know anything about strapi? Cause I've accessed data before in this fashion. Pretty straight forward, it seems very strange that I'm getting this error.

Comment: Without a real [mcve] we can only guess. Nothing in the shown script tries to access the content of `json`. You're constantly talking about `home` and that `console.log(home.Hero)` works but there's no `home` variable in the script nor a call for `console.log(home.Hero)`.

Comment: @Andreas home is coming redux store in 'state' 
const mapState = state => {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        home: state.fetchPagesReducer.home
    }
}
const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchHome: () => dispatch(fetchHome())
    }
}

Comment: Well, I've discovered that I have to 'explicitly' return ```home.Hero.url``` from the redux action/reducer. I don't know why it's not available in react from the 'state' object. I'll dig in and figure it out then post the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's happening.

> This is likely because at the moment of reading url from Hero, Hero is
> not yet defined (as the error message suggests). You could tackle this
> by first confirming Hero is defined before reading url. Something like
> this: console.log(home.Hero && home.Hero.url).
>
> Though this leads to a lot of cumbersome code, and therefor (imo) it
> would be better to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable to
> manage the data that is returned from the Strapi api.
>
> You would then set home as an immutable object (a Map) and read url
> like this: console.log(home.getIn([‘Hero’, ‘url’]). If Hero is
> undefined here your application will not crash, but instead false will
> be returned. - Boaz Poolman - slack.strapi